# How can I access the property in an object that has an unknown class?

Tags: objective-c, object, casting

My initial code was

```
[[[show Episodes] lastObject] setDescription:nodeContent];
```

This gets the last object from the Episodes array and tries to set the episode's description property using nodeContent. This does not work because I think the compiler does not know the class of the episode object.

I then tried providing a cast

```
((EpisodeRepresentation *)[[show Episodes] lastObject]).description = nodeContent;
```

This doesn't work either. I have also tried unsuccessfully

```
EpisodeRepresentation *rep = [[show Episodes] lastObject];
rep.description = nodeContent;
```

All these ways leave description null (nodeContent is definitely not null, it is a NSString).

Answer (score 4):

Your array is empty. Try `[[show Episodes] count]` to get the number of objects in the array.

BTW: Your naming of classes and methods seems odd. Classes usually begin with Captal letters and methods with lower case letters.

Comment: It's also possible that the array is `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed naming. I am sure that neither the array, nor the object is nil because I can view the objects using the debugger and they appear to exist and to contain the correct fields.

Comment: Show the description method and how nodeContent is created. Also tell us if you are using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

3 possibilities

1. array has no value make a check
2. show.episods doesnt have this object
3. nodecontent is null

description is an NSobject property which you are overriding here.Better use another property name for description